# Codenameone: Build-Error when integrating Codename One Native Data Transfer Library

Tags: codenameone

I tried to integrate the cn1lib for Native Data Transfer, which is available on the Extensions-Page. Unfortunately, when this lib is integrated, some build errors appear: Some awt-classes are missing (e.g. import java.awt.Component;).

I don't know, what exactly is missing to get the build done.

Here is the complete Console-Output with the build error:

```
    [echo] Compile is forcing compliance to the supported API's/features for maximum device compatibility. This allows smaller
    [echo]          code size and wider device support
    [copy] Copying 80 files to /Users/Klaus/Documents/workspace/GTD/build/tmp
   [javac] /Users/Klaus/Documents/workspace/GTD/build.xml:147: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
   [javac] Compiling 73 source files to /Users/Klaus/Documents/workspace/GTD/build/tmp
   [javac] Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
   [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
   [javac] Note: /Users/Klaus/Documents/workspace/GTD/src/de/zeitkuenstler/gtd/data/DBXAccess.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
   [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    [copy] Copying 4 files to /Users/Klaus/Documents/workspace/GTD/build/tmp
     [jar] Building jar: /Users/Klaus/Documents/workspace/GTD/dist/GTD.jar
   [javac] /Users/Klaus/Documents/workspace/GTD/build.xml:171: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
   [javac] Compiling 1 source file to /Users/Klaus/Documents/workspace/GTD/native/internal_tmp
   [javac] /Users/Klaus/Documents/workspace/GTD/lib/impl/native/javase/com/codename1/datatransfer/NativeDragAndDropImpl.java:5: error: package java.awt does not exist
   [javac] import java.awt.Component;
   [javac]                ^
   [javac] /Users/Klaus/Documents/workspace/GTD/lib/impl/native/javase/com/codename1/datatransfer/NativeDragAndDropImpl.java:6: error: package java.awt does not exist
   [javac] import java.awt.Container;
   [javac]                ^
   [javac] /Users/Klaus/Documents/workspace/GTD/lib/impl/native/javase/com/codename1/datatransfer/NativeDragAndDropImpl.java:7: error: package java.awt does not exist
   [javac] import java.awt.EventQueue;
   [javac]                ^
   [javac] /Users/Klaus/Documents/workspace/GTD/lib/impl/native/javase/com/codename1/datatransfer/NativeDragAndDropImpl.java:8: error: package java.awt does not exist
   [javac] import java.awt.Frame;
   [javac]                ^
   [javac] /Users/Klaus/Documents/workspace/GTD/lib/impl/native/javase/com/codename1/datatransfer/NativeDragAndDropImpl.java:9: error: package java.awt.datatransfer does not exist
   [javac] import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
   [javac]                             ^
   [javac] /Users/Klaus/Documents/workspace/GTD/lib/impl/native/javase/com/codename1/datatransfer/NativeDragAndDropImpl.java:10: error: package java.awt.datatransfer does not exist
   [javac] import java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable;
   [javac]                             ^
   [javac] /Users/Klaus/Documents/workspace/GTD/lib/impl/native/javase/com/codename1/datatransfer/NativeDragAndDropImpl.java:11: error: package java.awt.datatransfer does not exist
   [javac] import java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException;
   [javac]                             ^
   [javac] /Users/Klaus/Documents/workspace/GTD/lib/impl/native/javase/com/codename1/datatransfer/NativeDragAndDropImpl.java:12: error: package java.awt.dnd does not exist
   [javac] import java.awt.dnd.DnDConstants;
   [javac]                    ^
   [javac] /Users/Klaus/Documents/workspace/GTD/lib/impl/native/javase/com/codename1/datatransfer/NativeDragAndDropImpl.java:13: error: package java.awt.dnd does not exist
   [javac] import java.awt.dnd.DropTargetAdapter;
   [javac]                    ^
   [javac] /Users/Klaus/Documents/workspace/GTD/lib/impl/native/javase/com/codename1/datatransfer/NativeDragAndDropImpl.java:14: error: package java.awt.dnd does not exist
   [javac] import java.awt.dnd.DropTargetDropEvent;
   [javac]                    ^
   [javac] /Users/Klaus/Documents/workspace/GTD/lib/impl/native/javase/com/codename1/datatransfer/NativeDragAndDropImpl.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
   [javac] import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
   [javac]               ^
   [javac]   symbol:   class BufferedInputStream
   [javac]   location: package java.io
   [javac] /Users/Klaus/Documents/workspace/GTD/lib/impl/native/javase/com/codename1/datatransfer/NativeDragAndDropImpl.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
   [javac] import java.io.File;
   [javac]               ^
   [javac]   symbol:   class File
   [javac]   location: package java.io
   [javac] /Users/Klaus/Documents/workspace/GTD/lib/impl/native/javase/com/codename1/datatransfer/NativeDragAndDropImpl.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
   [javac] import java.io.FileInputStream;
   [javac]               ^
   [javac]   symbol:   class FileInputStream
   [javac]   location: package java.io
   [javac] /Users/Klaus/Documents/workspace/GTD/lib/impl/native/javase/com/codename1/datatransfer/NativeDragAndDropImpl.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
   [javac] import java.net.URLConnection;
   [javac]                ^
   [javac]   symbol:   class URLConnection
   [javac]   location: package java.net
   [javac] /Users/Klaus/Documents/workspace/GTD/lib/impl/native/javase/com/codename1/datatransfer/NativeDragAndDropImpl.java:22: error: package java.nio.file does not exist
   [javac] import java.nio.file.Files;
   [javac]                     ^
   [javac] /Users/Klaus/Documents/workspace/GTD/lib/impl/native/javase/com/codename1/datatransfer/NativeDragAndDropImpl.java:26: error: package javax.swing does not exist
   [javac] import javax.swing.JComponent;
   [javac]                   ^
   [javac] /Users/Klaus/Documents/workspace/GTD/lib/impl/native/javase/com/codename1/datatransfer/NativeDragAndDropImpl.java:27: error: package javax.swing does not exist
   [javac] import javax.swing.JFrame;
   [javac]                   ^
   [javac] /Users/Klaus/Documents/workspace/GTD/lib/impl/native/javase/com/codename1/datatransfer/NativeDragAndDropImpl.java:28: error: package javax.swing does not exist
   [javac] import javax.swing.JPanel;
   [javac]                   ^
   [javac] /Users/Klaus/Documents/workspace/GTD/lib/impl/native/javase/com/codename1/datatransfer/NativeDragAndDropImpl.java:32: error: package java.awt.dnd does not exist
   [javac]     java.awt.dnd.DropTarget dropTarget;
   [javac]                 ^
   [javac] /Users/Klaus/Documents/workspace/GTD/lib/impl/native/javase/com/codename1/datatransfer/NativeDragAndDropImpl.java:34: error: cannot find symbol
   [javac]     private Component findCanvas(Component c, Set<Component> checked) {
   [javac]                                  ^
   [javac]   symbol:   class Component
   [javac]   location: class NativeDragAndDropImpl
   [javac] /Users/Klaus/Documents/workspace/GTD/lib/impl/native/javase/com/codename1/datatransfer/NativeDragAndDropImpl.java:34: error: cannot find symbol
   [javac]     private Component findCanvas(Component c, Set<Component> checked) {
   [javac]                                                   ^
   [javac]   symbol:   class Component
   [javac]   location: class NativeDragAndDropImpl
   [javac] /Users/Klaus/Documents/workspace/GTD/lib/impl/native/javase/com/codename1/datatransfer/NativeDragAndDropImpl.java:34: error: cannot find symbol
   [javac]     private Component findCanvas(Component c, Set<Component> checked) {
   [javac]             ^
   [javac]   symbol:   class Component
   [javac]   location: class NativeDragAndDropImpl
   [javac] /Users/Klaus/Documents/workspace/GTD/lib/impl/native/javase/com/codename1/datatransfer/NativeDragAndDropImpl.java:60: error: cannot find symbol
   [javac]     private Component findCanvas(Component c) {
   [javac]                                  ^
   [javac]   symbol:   class Component
   [javac]   location: class NativeDragAndDropImpl
   [javac] /Users/Klaus/Documents/workspace/GTD/lib/impl/native/javase/com/codename1/datatransfer/NativeDragAndDropImpl.java:60: error: cannot find symbol
   [javac]     private Component findCanvas(Component c) {
   [javac]             ^
   [javac]   symbol:   class Component
   [javac]   location: class NativeDragAndDropImpl
   [javac] /Users/Klaus/Documents/workspace/GTD/lib/impl/native/javase/com/codename1/datatransfer/NativeDragAndDropImpl.java:42: error: cannot find symbol
   [javac]         if (c instanceof JComponent) {
   [javac]                          ^
   [javac]   symbol:   class JComponent
   [javac]   location: class NativeDragAndDropImpl
   [javac] /Users/Klaus/Documents/workspace/GTD/lib/impl/native/javase/com/codename1/datatransfer/NativeDragAndDropImpl.java:45: error: cannot find symbol
   [javac]                 JComponent jc = (JComponent)c;
   [javac]                 ^
   [javac]   symbol:   class JComponent
   [javac]   location: class NativeDragAndDropImpl
   [javac] /Users/Klaus/Documents/workspace/GTD/lib/impl/native/javase/com/codename1/datatransfer/NativeDragAndDropImpl.java:45: error: cannot find symbol
   [javac]                 JComponent jc = (JComponent)c;
   [javac]                                  ^
   [javac]   symbol:   class JComponent
   [javac]   location: class NativeDragAndDropImpl
   [javac] /Users/Klaus/Documents/workspace/GTD/lib/impl/native/javase/com/codename1/datatransfer/NativeDragAndDropImpl.java:46: error: cannot find symbol
   [javac]                 Component[] children = jc.getComponents();
   [javac]                 ^
   [javac]   symbol:   class Component
   [javac]   location: class NativeDragAndDropImpl
   [javac] /Users/Klaus/Documents/workspace/GTD/lib/impl/native/javase/com/codename1/datatransfer/NativeDragAndDropImpl.java:47: error: cannot find symbol
   [javac]                 for (Component child : children){
   [javac]                      ^
   [javac]   symbol:   class Component
   [javac]   location: class NativeDragAndDropImpl
   [javac] /Users/Klaus/Documents/workspace/GTD/lib/impl/native/javase/com/codename1/datatransfer/NativeDragAndDropImpl.java:48: error: cannot find symbol
   [javac]                     Component found = findCanvas(child, checked);
   [javac]                     ^
   [javac]   symbol:   class Component
   [javac]   location: class NativeDragAndDropImpl
   [javac] /Users/Klaus/Documents/workspace/GTD/lib/impl/native/javase/com/codename1/datatransfer/NativeDragAndDropImpl.java:61: error: cannot find symbol
   [javac]         return findCanvas(c, new HashSet<Component>());
   [javac]                                          ^
   [javac]   symbol:   class Component
   [javac]   location: class NativeDragAndDropImpl
   [javac] /Users/Klaus/Documents/workspace/GTD/lib/impl/native/javase/com/codename1/datatransfer/NativeDragAndDropImpl.java:70: error: cannot find symbol
   [javac]                Frame[] frames = Frame.getFrames();
   [javac]                ^
   [javac]   symbol: class Frame
   [javac] /Users/Klaus/Documents/workspace/GTD/lib/impl/native/javase/com/codename1/datatransfer/NativeDragAndDropImpl.java:70: error: cannot find symbol
   [javac]                Frame[] frames = Frame.getFrames();
   [javac]                                 ^
   [javac]   symbol: variable Frame
   [javac] /Users/Klaus/Documents/workspace/GTD/lib/impl/native/javase/com/codename1/datatransfer/NativeDragAndDropImpl.java:71: error: cannot find symbol
   [javac]                 JPanel canvas = null;
   [javac]                 ^
   [javac]   symbol: class JPanel
   [javac] /Users/Klaus/Documents/workspace/GTD/lib/impl/native/javase/com/codename1/datatransfer/NativeDragAndDropImpl.java:72: error: cannot find symbol
   [javac]                 for (Frame frame : frames) {
   [javac]                      ^
   [javac]   symbol: class Frame
   [javac] /Users/Klaus/Documents/workspace/GTD/lib/impl/native/javase/com/codename1/datatransfer/NativeDragAndDropImpl.java:73: error: cannot find symbol
   [javac]                     if (frame instanceof JFrame) {
   [javac]                                          ^
   [javac]   symbol: class JFrame
   [javac] /Users/Klaus/Documents/workspace/GTD/lib/impl/native/javase/com/codename1/datatransfer/NativeDragAndDropImpl.java:74: error: cannot find symbol
   [javac]                         JFrame jframe = (JFrame)frame;
   [javac]                         ^
   [javac]   symbol: class JFrame
   [javac] /Users/Klaus/Documents/workspace/GTD/lib/impl/native/javase/com/codename1/datatransfer/NativeDragAndDropImpl.java:74: error: cannot find symbol
   [javac]                         JFrame jframe = (JFrame)frame;
   [javac]                                          ^
   [javac]   symbol: class JFrame
   [javac] /Users/Klaus/Documents/workspace/GTD/lib/impl/native/javase/com/codename1/datatransfer/NativeDragAndDropImpl.java:75: error: cannot find symbol
   [javac]                         canvas = (JPanel)findCanvas(jframe.getContentPane());
   [javac]                                   ^
   [javac]   symbol: class JPanel
   [javac] /Users/Klaus/Documents/workspace/GTD/lib/impl/native/javase/com/codename1/datatransfer/NativeDragAndDropImpl.java:81: error: cannot find symbol
   [javac]                 final JPanel fcanvas = canvas;
   [javac]                       ^
   [javac]   symbol: class JPanel
   [javac] /Users/Klaus/Documents/workspace/GTD/lib/impl/native/javase/com/codename1/datatransfer/NativeDragAndDropImpl.java:82: error: package java.awt.dnd does not exist
   [javac]                 dropTarget = new java.awt.dnd.DropTarget(canvas, new DropTargetAdapter() {
   [javac]                                              ^
   [javac] /Users/Klaus/Documents/workspace/GTD/lib/impl/native/javase/com/codename1/datatransfer/NativeDragAndDropImpl.java:82: error: cannot find symbol
   [javac]                 dropTarget = new java.awt.dnd.DropTarget(canvas, new DropTargetAdapter() {
   [javac]                                                                      ^
   [javac]   symbol: class DropTargetAdapter
   [javac] /Users/Klaus/Documents/workspace/GTD/lib/impl/native/javase/com/codename1/datatransfer/NativeDragAndDropImpl.java:65: error: cannot find symbol
   [javac]         EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
   [javac]         ^
   [javac]   symbol:   variable EventQueue
   [javac]   location: class NativeDragAndDropImpl
   [javac] 43 errors
```

BUILD FAILED
/Users/Klaus/Documents/workspace/GTD/build.xml:171: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Comment: How did you install the library?  Through Codename One settings, or another way?

Comment: Through the settings-section - including the call of "refresh Libs"

Comment: Can you list the exact errors that you got? Do you get them when right clicking the project and doing a build?

Comment: I added the complete console output with the build error at the first post. I get this errors after the automatic build which is started, when I refresh the CN1LIBs. By the way: I use Eclipse as my IDE.

Answer (score 2):

There appears to be a bug in the Eclipse build.xml template in the current version.  I have applied a fix that will be included with the next plugin update.  In the mean time, you'll need to make a small change to your build.xml file.

Around line 170 of your build.xml, there is a javac call:

```
<javac destdir="native/internal_tmp" compiler="modern"
            source="1.8"
            target="1.8"
            bootclasspath="lib/CLDC11.jar"
            classpath="lib/CodenameOne.jar:${build.classes.dir}:lib/impl/cls:build/tmp">
            <src path="native/javase"/>
            <src path="lib/impl/native/javase"/>
        </javac>
```

Remove the `bootclasspath=` line, so you end up with:

```
<javac destdir="native/internal_tmp" compiler="modern"
            source="1.8"
            target="1.8"
            classpath="lib/CodenameOne.jar:${build.classes.dir}:lib/impl/cls:build/tmp">
            <src path="native/javase"/>
            <src path="lib/impl/native/javase"/>
        </javac>
```